# Is there any limits for number of properties used in templates in Semantic Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

Is there any limits for number of properties used in templates?
We use a lot of properties in dozens templates.
But from one time we can not add any new reusable property to our templates.
We can create new property, add it value at the page as in-text with the #set or[[]] clauses.
And we can use it by semantic search.
But when we add the property in template and add the value as template values, the SW didn't see it value and the semantic search didn't find it.

We move from MW 1.29.1 and SMW 2.5.5 to new version -"smw": "3.1.5",
"mediawiki": "1.34.0",
and run rebuild script with any key combinations. But this didn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Its a classical drawback of SMW.

I haven't dig technically on the matter, but I presume that their is a conflict with a standard mediawiki mechanism, which ignores a page save without modification of page content.

From the page point of view, a change inside the template doesn't modify its content...

To be refreshed, the page content needs to be edited and saved, with a modification.

A quick and dirty fix is to program a bot that adds a space character at the end of page content for every needed page, thus triggering re-parsing of the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a template problem.

Some logic used in your templates could prevent SMW from indexing the properties

make sure the `{{#set:` isn't inside a `{{#if:` or `<noninclude>`

One of the SMW maintenance scripts should take care of indexing the properties from the pages again after changes are made to the used template.

For example this will be indexed if you save the page manually but may not be index by a maintenance script.

`{{#if: {{CURRENTLOGGEDUSER}} | {{#set:Key=Value|Key2={{{templateValue|}}} }} }}`